# Including common Django Project in multiple projects

Tags: python, django

I have two Django Projects where I use a lot of common models. Custom user classes, Algorithm classes, Product classes. The two projects are related to e-commerce, both run on different machines and serve completely different purposes.

However, considering that they have these models in "common", I was wondering if it would be worth it to create a third, common project that serves as the "base" with the base models, and then both of these projects would import the common models from this base project.

This would also help as we can join the two different customer and product databases from both e-commerce websites into this big common database.

My questions are:
1) Does anybody have any experience with the possible overhead or can realistically estimate it? Joining the common parts of both Django projects will be necessary down the road, but I estimate there will be a lot of overhead in importing a third project (possibly in real-time).

2) What would be the best approach to importin this third project? I can think of multiple ways:

- Creating a packaged, installable Python module such as the existing ones on the internet (setuptools, lxml, tastypie) and importing that module into both Django projects;
- Having the project sit on a directory in a machine and importing from that path in real-time inside the Python file (have done it before, works but seems to have some overhead);

EDIT: Our common models/functionality, additionally, contain trade-secreted and patenteable content, therefore public distribution is out of the question. I am guessing the route would be to create something like a package, but not publicly distributed, only distributed and installed on the 2 specific machines.

Can anybody give some feedback on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate out the common models, ect... into it's own python package. Then each project will have this package installed, or just install the package at the system level and they both can use it. If you handle this properly you shouldn't have to change much of your imports and you can easily update the package by pushing a new egg to the server and installing via `easy_install` or `pip`.

This is the way that I currently have my projects setup. Common non-business logic is separated out into their own project and I create a package from this and then install and use like any other python library.

The little bit of extra work here can save you a lot of time and allows for transparent updating of your common code between various projects as well.

Comment: This seems a good solution. However, we have trade-secreted material in our common material, therefore it can't be publicly acessible. Can we create and distribute the created module in private only for the selected machines?

Comment: Yes you can setup a private repo locally, or you can just install from the egg file itself you do not need to upload it up to pypi for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Organize your Models into logical Apps within a single project.

For example a single project with 4 apps:

```
myproject/
    blog/
    contact/
    project1specific/
    project2specific/
```

Use the Sites Framework:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Have 2 settings.py files (settings_p1.py, settings_p2.py)

In each of the Settings files set SITE_ID to a different value for each project.

```
SITE_ID = 1 (or 2 for the second project)
```

Don't forget to actually create the second Site record in your sites table!

In the INSTALLED_APPS within each settings.py ONLY include the apps that you want to use for this specific project.

Maybe set 2 different template directories, STATIC_ROOT (MEDIA_ROOT would probably stay the same) and urls files in the 2 project's settings files.

At this point you can either use different DB settings per project settings.py OR add a Site FK to your models and make the AdminForms queryset reflect the current site records only.

Let me know if you need any specifics, but this is how I would accomplish what you are doing.

Comment: Thank for the in-depth solution. The problem is, both projects are massive. Each supports thousands of active users and similarly thousands of products. And as such, each project already has about 5-10 submodules. I reckon joining both projects with their submodules into one big project would be going backwards, because instead of encapsulating functionality you would be going the other way?

Comment: yea my solution is what we do for mobile sites when it's loosely coupled with the desktop version, but has enough differences to require 2 sets of apps/templates/urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to support these applications in parallel for the foreseeable future, this is absolutely worth it. There's nothing more depressing than making a change to one thing and then repeating it almost verbatim in another place, especially if weird project-specific bugs start cropping up because the two remained subtly different.

One way of achieving such sharing that you have not listed could be [git submodules](http://markhansen.co.nz/git-repo-inside-git/) or felixge's [Git Fake Submodules](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb).